# npm run watch stuck on loading

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

`npm run watch` leads me to a page that never loads. Here's the step by step:

- I start a fresh project by running `laravel new my-app`. I'm using Laravel 5.8
- I go to my-app and install dependencies by running `cd my-app && npm install`. Here's the `package.json` file:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17"
    }
}
```

- after it's done, I works as expected on `php artisan serve`
- `npm run dev` also compiles the app.js and app.scss perfectly
- when I run `npm run watch`, it builds it correctly but I can't access it through the regular `localhost:3000`. Also, I'd expect the tab to automatically be opened up as soon as everything's compiled, which was not the case
- so I try to configure it myself with `browserSync` option on laravel mix. Here's my `webpack.mix.js` file after that:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */
mix
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');

mix.browserSync('http://localhost:3000');
```

- then I run `npm run watch` again. BrowserSync seems to work, I can access its UI. Here's the output:

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 5380ms                                  15:18:33

       Asset      Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
/css/app.css   173 KiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
  /js/app.js  1.38 MiB  /js/app  [emitted]  /js/app
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://localhost:3000
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.0.163:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Watching files...
```

- however, when I access `http://localhost:3000`, it shows a blank page that never loads. The console shows no error
- I tried to use a proxy option like `mix.browserSync('my-app.dev')` on browserSync, but it gives `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error
- I tried it on chrome, but the same thing happens on my firefox, in which I've never installed any plugin and I basically don't even use

Comment: Go to Chrome Devtools -> Network tab. What does it show?

Comment: just a "localhost" file with 0KB and time pending when I go to "http://localhost:3000". When I use something like "my-app.dev", it returns a my-app.dev document with status (failed), 0KB size and time of 14 ms

Comment: did you resolve this problem? i have exactly the same.

Comment: Afraid I've just got a "me too" to add! Works great on my original development machine, then added it to GitHub, cloned on another two machines, can't get either of them working. Using internal server (php artisan serve) works great, using npm run watch with browsersync gives a browser window that never loads. Going to dig into this some more, promise to report back if I fix it!

Comment: I promised to come back, so here I am... Seems I had a fundamental misunderstanding as to how browsersync works, it can only serve static pages by itself (not PHP). For that you need another web server running (in my case Apache as part of XAMPP) and browsersync will proxy to it and automatically reload pages as required. As soon as I start Apache, browsersync starts working

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem last week and it's due to a misunderstanding in how BrowserSync works.

The internal server in BrowserSync only hosts static HTML/JS/CSS pages (as referenced in [the BrowserSync documentation](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-server))

It will however act as a proxy for an existing web application that is being served by another web server, and then do its magic with refreshing your browser when you update anything.

So the solution therefore is to host your Laravel project on a web server, then use `npm run watch` to start BrowserSync. I would recommend [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) as it's very easy to use

Comment: Exactly. I forgot to run `php artisan serve` before

Answer (score -2):

I have been through this problem few days ago 
I tried to run **Xammp Apache server** and it worked for me, so give it a try

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to ultiple questions.

Comment: excuse me, it was an accident. I deleted the wrong one